# Iterate trough every word from WordsArray to take every character from it

Tags: swift

I'm making some hangman app so words i use should be displayed with "?" instead of letters

```
 if let wordsUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", withExtension: "txt"){
        if let wordsContent = try? String(contentsOf: wordUrl){
            var allWords = wordsContent.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

I don't know how to index every word from allWords array.? After that i would change letters using another property which i would use to display

```
  for letter in word {
                usedLetters.append(letter)
                promptWord.append("?")
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean with “index every word”? You have an array with the words so each word already have an index in the array. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I want to iterate through every word from allWords array. And for every letter in certain word i want to append one "?" to promptWord. I was thinking about nested for loop but still don't know how to do it either-@JoakimDanielson

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like your `allWords` is `[String]` with each word being a separate element.  In that case, the first word is `allWords[0]`, the second word is `allWords[1]`, etc...  But you can loop through them as `for word in allWords` in same manner that you loop through the characters of the words.   Or loop through its indices (`for wordIndex in allWords.indices { let word = allWords[wordIndex]...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d recommend creating a method which you can call whenever your text field needs updating due to something such as a new letter input from the user.

```
var wordTextField: UITextField!
var usedWords = [] // Array to track the words already used by the user
let word = "hangman" // Word for the user to guess
var promptWord = "" // What will be displayed in the wordTextField
func updateTextField() {
    for letter in word.uppercased() {
        let strLetter = String(letter)
        
        if usedLetters.contains(strLetter) {
            promptWord += strLetter
        } else {
            promptWord += "?"
        }
    }
    wordTextField.text = promptWord
```

A brief explanation of what the code does:

- Firstly it iterates through the word inspecting each letter (uppercase so that there are no inconsistencies with the characters when the comparison is made to what the user has entered as their guess).
- Secondly it checks to see if the `strLetter` is contained within the `usedLetters` array if it is then it places the letter inside of the correct location in the `promptWord`.
- Whenever the letter is not found to be contained within the `usedWords` array a “?” is instead added to the string.
- Finally the text of the `wordTextField` is set to be the `promptWord` displaying the amount of letters which the user has left to guess and how many as well as which letters the user has guessed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a String to an array of characters:

```
let string = "a String"
let characters = Array(characters)
```

So you could map your array of words to an array of arrays of characters like this:

```
var allWordsAsCharacterArrays = allWords.map { Array($0) }
```

You can also populate strings with question marks using `String.init(repeating:count:)`

When you pick a word from your words array, you could convert it to an array of characters, and a working string that you would populate with an array of question marks. As the user picks letters, you could replace the question marks in the working string with the correct letters from the word they are guessing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just trying to provide the user ultimately with a hidden word containing only question marks. May I suggest a more straight forward approach?

```
let wordToGuess = "Hangman"
let hiddenWord = String(repeating: "?", count: wordToGuess.count)
```

now when the user guesses you can replace the proper characters

```
        let guess = "h" // get from your user input 
    if wordToGuess.localizedStandardContains(guess) {
        
        var location = 0
        for c in wordToGuess {
            if c.lowercased() == guess.lowercased() {

                let index = hiddenWord.index(hiddenWord.startIndex, offsetBy: location)
                hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replacingCharacters(in: index...index , with: String(c) )
                print("hidden word now: \(hiddenWord)")
            }
            location += 1
        }
    }
```

note this is pretty messy code. It works, but I'm sure there is a much better way.

Comment: With little modification of your example code i did my method well. I mean it may not be best solution or maybe something you would write but for now it works. Thank you.